# Flink Watermark strategy

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are building a stream processing pipeline to process Kinesis messages using Flink v1.11 and Event time characteristics. While defining a source watermark strategy, in the official documentation, I came across two out-of-the-box watermark strategies; forBoundedOutOfOrderness and forMonotonousTimestamps. But I dont think these fit my usecase as per my understanding of the above. Here are the details on my usecase:

Data from input stream: (containing data with timestamps for each minute)

```
{11:00, Data1}
{11:01, Data2}
{11:00, Data3}
{11:00, Data4}
{11:01, Data5}
...
```

Now, I want to process the window (Tumbling event time: 1min) for 11:00-11:01 containing [Data1, Data3, Data4] exactly 20 seconds after the first event with 11:00 timestamp arrived. Similarly, the next window from 11:01-11:02 containing [Data2, Data5] needs to be executed 20s post the first event with 11:01 timestamp comes in. Is this kind of watermark strategy possible in Flink?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach for implementing this:

In the `onEvent` method keep track of the largest timestamp seen so far. And whenever you update this variable, record the current system time.

Then when `onPeriodicEmit` is called (by default this will be called every 200 msec), if it has been 20 seconds since the current max timestamp was updated, emit a watermark equal to the current max timestamp plus 1 second.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the detailed response, David!. Just one follow up question, incase the largest timestamp changes before the first 20s of previous largest timestamp (say at current time = 11:01:00, the first 11:00 event timestamp event comes and at current time = 11:01:10, the first 11:01 event timestamp event comes in), the watermark will be emitted 20s after the second largest timestamp...right? Would I need to maintain map of maxTimestamps and current timestamps in that case for which watermark is not emitted yet? or is this scenario not possible.

Comment: Yes, if that sort of overlap is possible, then you might need to use a map to handle events from different time ranges. I was assuming a simpler case, where the events won't exhibit that much out-of-orderness.